# Decrypt second encrypted LVM during headless server boot?

Tags: ubuntu, lvm, luks

I've followed this question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5017/ssh-to-decrypt-encrypted-lvm-during-headless-server-boot and successfully remotely decrypted my root drive. However, I have a second drive that I also have encrpted, and unfortunately dropbear is killed by the boot process before second passphrase prompt for the second drive is shown and the main open-ssh server has not yet started so once again the headless system sits waiting for input indefinitely.

Is there any way round this?

The second drive will be used for private cloud data storage so needs to be encrypted to protect the data, and needs to be decrypted before the cloud service starts (which I haven't chosen or installed yet).

Ubuntu 13.10 x64 server running headless, though I'm not totally tied to Ubuntu it is kinda convenient.

Comment: similar question: http://serverfault.com/q/337752/15016

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this is to add a derived key from the first partition to to the second disk by running:

```
/lib/cryptsetup/scripts/decrypt_derived sda1_crypt > new_key_file
cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/sdb1 new_key_file  # prompts for an existing key
shred -u new_key_file                        # remove the key file
```

Then replace the `sdb1_crypt` line in /etc/crypttab with:

```
sdb1_crypt /dev/sdb1 sda1_crypt \
    luks,keyscript=/lib/cryptsetup/scripts/decrypt_derived
```

With this, the second disk can be automatically mounted as soon as the first disk is available.

Of course, you need to replace `sda1` and `sdb1` with the correct partitions/labels you use and do not forget to run `update-initramfs -u` after the change and to add a corresponding entry to `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: Many thanks for the pointer to decrypt_derived, I hadn't come across it before. I'll do a bit more reading and see how I get on.

Comment: Found these related questions: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32541/linux-luks-and-multiple-hard-drives and http://askubuntu.com/questions/43432/stop-crypttab-asking-for-password-for-swap and this informative cryptsetup faq https://code.google.com/p/cryptsetup/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions

Comment: I have a question I haven't been able to figure out / google the answer to yet. If I do the above will I still be able to use the existing passphrase to decrypt sdb1, or will I have to use key from sda from then on? I ask because I don't mind losing sda so much as it's just the system disk and is encrypted to protect cached data and the swap partition, I care more about sdb as that's where the user data will be. So if sda fails, does that make sdb permanently irrecoverable? (Assuming I don't backup sda's luks header)

Comment: @TimAbell With luks, you can have up to 8 keys per device. The luksAddKey command adds another key to the existing one. It does not replace it - so it the command should be safe. It prompts for an existing key, not the new one.

Comment: @TimAbell The luksAddKey command was wrong in the answer (did simply not work without any damage). I fixed it now. On journal filesystems, the `shred` command may not work properly. To be on the safe side, put the temporary file with the new key on a tmpfs.

Comment: Brilliant that's unlocking both at once. Many thanks. I found another related question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5017/ssh-to-decrypt-encrypted-lvm-during-headless-server-boot

Comment: don't forget to run this as `root` otherwise you get the rather cryptic `/lib/cryptsetup/scripts/decrypt_derived: failed to find sda1_crypt in dmtable`