# Using a single passphrase to unlock multiple encrypted disks at boot

Tags: linux, disk-encryption, cryptsetup

My machine has an SSD, where I installed the system and an HDD, which I use as a storage for large and/or infrequently used files. Both are encrypted, but I chose to use the same passphrase for them. SSD is mounted at `/` and HDD at `/usr/hdd` (individual users each have a directory on it and can symlink as they like from home directory).

When the system is booted, it immediately asks for passphrase for the SSD, and just a couple seconds later for the one for HDD (it is auto-mounted). **Given that both passphrases are the same, is there a way to configure the system to ask just once?**

Comment: You could possibly write an `expect` script or similar that gets called to mount the disks instead of having the system do it.  Instead, the system would call the script which would ask for the password, store it, and provide it to each of the mount operations.

Comment: If I understand your idea correctly, it cannot be applied to the SSD, since that's where the system boots from. But then it becomes pointless, as I still would need to type the passphrase for the HDD separately. Or no?

Comment: You can use `/etc/crypttab` [to unlock the second drive](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/System_configuration#crypttab).

Comment: @jasonwryan if that can be expanded to an answer then ... answers should be posted as answers, not comments.

Comment: @derobert sometimes people don't have the time, or the inclination, to write up a good answer.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

### Debian based distributions:

Debian and Ubuntu ship a password caching script *decrypt_keyctl* with [*cryptsetup*](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=decrypt_keyctl) package.

*decrypt_keyctl* script provides the same password to multiple encrypted LUKS targets, saving you from typing it multiple times. It can be enabled in [*crypttab*](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/cryptsetup-run/crypttab.5.en.html) with `keyscript=decrypt_keyctl` option. The same password is used for targets which have the same identifier in *keyfile field*. On boot password for each identifier is asked once.

An example *crypttab*:

```
<target>      <source>         <keyfile>      <options>
part1_crypt   /dev/disk/...    crypt_disks    luks,keyscript=decrypt_keyctl
part2_crypt   /dev/disk/...    crypt_disks    luks,keyscript=decrypt_keyctl
```

The `decrypt_keyctl` script depends on the `keyutils` package (which is only suggested, and therefore not necessarily installed).

After you've updated your *cryptab*, you will also have to update initramfs to apply the changes. Use [`update-initramfs -u`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man8/update-initramfs.8.html).

Full readme for decrypt_keyctl is located in `/usr/share/doc/cryptsetup/README.keyctl`

---

### Distributions which do not provide *decrypt_keyctl* script:

If *decrypt_keyctrl* isn't provided by your distribution, the device can be unlocked using a keyfile in encrypted root file system. This when root file system can be unlocked and mounted before of any other encrypted devices.

LUKS supports multiple key slots. This allows you to alternatively unlock the device using password if the key file is unavailable/lost.

1. Generate the key with random data and set its permissions to owner readable only to avoid leaking it. Note that the key file needs to be on the root partition which is unlocked first.

   ```
    dd if=/dev/urandom of=<path to key file> bs=1024 count=1
    chmod u=rw,g=,o= <path to key file>
   ```
2. Add the key to your LUKS device

   ```
    cryptsetup luksAddKey <path to encrypted device> <path to key file>
   ```
3. Configure *crypttab* to use the key file. First line should be the root device, since devices are unlocked in same order as listed in *crypttab*. Use absolute paths for key files.

   ```
    <target>      <source>         <keyfile>                  <options>
    root_crypt    /dev/disk/...    none                       luks
    part1_crypt   /dev/disk/...    <path to key file>         luks
   ```

Comment: From the first lines of the readme it looks very promising, thank you. I'll check this tomorrow (don't want to reboot now).

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work (as in no change). See [my `crypttab`](https://paste.debian.net/986341/) (I didn't touch `UUID=` created by the system installer,
 I guess it shouldn't matter) and [resulting entries in `/var/log/syslog`](https://paste.debian.net/986343/). The errors are sort of understandable, but I have no idea what to do about them. File `/lib/cryptsetup/scripts/decrypt_keyctl` exists, so I don't know why it complains about unknown option. I also have no idea what to specify as keyfile, I see no explanation anywhere...

Comment: Did you verify decrypt_keyctl gets included in initramfs? Check it using verbose option when updating the image: `update-initramfs -u -k $(uname -r) -v`, it should output `Adding binary /lib/cryptsetup/scripts/decrypt_keyctl`.

Comment: To see what initramfs contains: `lsinitramfs /boot/initrd.img-$(uname -r)`

Comment: Uh, sorry, now that I paid more attention to what `update-initramfs` said, I noticed this: `E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/cryptkeyctl failed with return 1.`. After a bit of googling, I found out that I probably need `keyutils` package (really was not installed). Now `update-initramfs` succeeds and `lsinitramfs` does mention `decrypt_keytls`. Will update after the next boot (likely tomorrow).

Comment: I've tested the script and it does work on my debian (sid) box with above configuration.

Comment: Hm, it still doesn't work... I still get the same errors in the log (path not absolute, option unknown), even though `lsinitramfs` does list `lib/cryptsetup/scripts/decrypt_keyctl`. I'm still asked twice for the passphrase, although *the first* time (for the root-mounted SSD) the prompt did mention that passphrase was going to be cached... Do I need to do anything to create the keystore file first?

Comment: The `path not absolute, option unknown` error  is printed when root (and other cryptsetup devices) are already unlocked, so it is not likely related. Since the prompt mentioned the password being cached, the script at is used but for some reason the password isn't re-used for the second device.

Comment: Here are [all the log entries](https://paste.debian.net/hidden/d2d6b141/) from today.

Comment: As it reads, the first device `nvme0n1p3_crypt` is already unlocked: `Volume nvme0n1p3_crypt already active`. Does the system ask for password second time after initramfs phase?

Comment: I'm not sure how to tell `initramfs` phase. The first time it asks for that `nvme...` passphrase (the SSD), because the entire system (other than `/boot` I guess) is encrypted and unaccessible until this disk is unlocked. Then it proceeds to boot, e.g. changes monitor resolution and after a few moments ask for the passphrase to unlock the HDD (mounted to `/usr/hdd`). It doesn't really *need* it, just it is set up to be auto-mounted. So, from what I can say it asks once for each physical disk.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65799/discussion-between-sebasth-and-doublep).

Comment: The second solution worked and achieves the same end result (typing the passphrase just once). Thank you.

Comment: Quick addendum to tighten up security a bit, `chattr +i <path to key file>` from the `chattr` manpage "A file with the 'i' attribute cannot be modified: it cannot be deleted or renamed, no link can be created to this file and no data can be written to the file. Only the superuser or a process possessing the CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE capability can set or clear this attribute. "

Comment: Tried in Linux Mint 19 (based on Ubuntu 18.04): just having the same password for both devices in `/etc/crypttab` was enough for the system to ask for password just once on boot at first. But once I added the second device as a new PV to the root LV (with LVM), the system started to ask for the same password twice at boot (probably because it could not read the root partition any more until both devices were unlocked?). Using `decrypt_keyctl` works then, so the mentioned systemd bug must have been fixed meanwhile.

Comment: Tested the `luks,initramfs,keyscript=decrypt_keyctl` crypttab options on Ubuntu 20.04 and I can confirm that the `initramfs` option workaround works as described.

Comment: Does that systemd bug still exist?

Comment: @Scorpion `decrypt_keyctl` seems to work on ubuntu 18.04, not sure if it works on debian.

Comment: @sebasth `decrypt_keyctl` with initramfs works on Debian 11, but with a keyfile doesn't work.

Comment: On Debian 12 `decrypt_keyctl` works without any workaround.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to use the `/lib/cryptsetup/scripts/decrypt_derived` script, which is also part of cryptsetup in Debian/Ubuntu.

Instead of caching the key, you use the volume key of one disk as an additional password for the second disk. This requires adding a second password to the second (and third, etc) encrypted disk, but LUKS supports that. This solution therefore also works if your multiple encrypted disks do not use the same password.

Example to add the key from sda6crypt to sda5:

Add volume key of sda6crypt as additional password for sda5:

```
mkfifo fifo
/lib/cryptsetup/scripts/decrypt_derived sda6crypt > fifo &
cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/sda5 fifo
rm fifo
```

Configure sda5crypt to be unlocked automatically in `/etc/crypttab`

```
ls -la /dev/disk/by-uuid/ | grep sda5
echo "sda5crypt UUID=<uuid> sda6crypt luks,initramfs,keyscript=/lib/cryptsetup/scripts/decrypt_derived" >> /etc/crypttab
```

This uses a named pipe (`fifo`) to pass the key to avoid having to store the volume key in a temporary file on disk.

The `keyscript` option only works if `crypttab` is processed by Debian's original cryptsetup tools, the systemd reimplementation does not currently support it. If your system uses systemd (which is most systems), you need the `initramfs` option to force processing to happen in the initrd by the cryptsetup tools, before systemd starts up.

Based on https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/32551/50793

Comment: Gotta say this a beautiful solution  Worked right off the bat no hiccups on debian 10 buster!

Comment: If your distribution provides `decrypt_keyctl` and that works for you, you should probably use that in favor of `decrypt_derived`. It also works with luks2 and doesn't remember the password for more than 60 seconds. If `decrypt_keyctl` does not work for you, I would say using `decrypt_derived` is preferable to using a regular keyfile.

Comment: As @JanKanis hinted, it looks like `decrypt_derived` is completely broken for LUKS2. Does anyone have more details on this? I just get `/lib/cryptsetup/scripts/decrypt_derived: device sda3_crypt uses the kernel keyring`. I need a way to unlock a disk which is connected later, after the 60 seconds.

Comment: @bitinerant `decrypt_keyctl` is a shellscript that uses the kernel keyring through `keyctl`. There is probably some way to change the timeout. Or you could write a script that retrieves the luks2 key from the kernel keyring.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my workaround on debian, given the bug referenced above by @sebasth.

My setup is slightly different. I have an encrypted root partition and a bunch of raid disks. For me, I had to add a initramfs option to the crypttab:

```
<target>      <source>         <keyfile>      <options>
part1_crypt   /dev/disk/...    crypt_disks    plain,cipher=aes-xts-plain64,keyscript=decrypt_keyctl,initramfs
part2_crypt   /dev/disk/...    crypt_disks    plain,cipher=aes-xts-plain64,keyscript=decrypt_keyctl,initramfs
```

This tells update-initramfs that I want to have these crypttab entries mounted in the initramfs. I checked my crypttab by running

```
cryptdisks_start part1_crypt
cryptdisks_start part2_crypt
```

Note that my raid disks are plain dm-crypt. This meant that I could not use the luks keyfile method that works around the systemd keyscript bug. For plain dm-crypt, I would have to store the passphrase in plaintext.

The package keyutils has to be installed and the encrypted disks have to be mounted before `update-initramfs` is run ; otherwise it will throw errors. I had to look for the following lines when my initramfs was built:

```
update-initramfs -u -v | grep 'keyctl'
```

which showed the following two files:

```
/bin/keyctl
cryptkeyctl
```

being added to the initramfs.

Finally, I had to disable systemd handling my crypttab, to deal with the bug referenced above: systemd does not support the keyscript option in crypttab. For this, I added the kernel option

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet luks.crypttab=no"
```

to /etc/default/grub and ran `update-grub`. systemd now ignores crypttab, and all the encrypted partitions are loaded in the initramfs.

Because I have an encrypted root partition, cryptroot does not appear to cache my key. This means I have to enter my password twice; one for the root partition and once for my raid array.

Comment: So, you did all this for nothing? You still have to enter multiple passwords.

Comment: No, once for the root partition and once for the 4 disk raid array. I cannot get it to just take one password for the root partition and raid array. There is probably a way to do this by editing the debian initramfs scripts.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case this helps anyone out: this should just happen on most systemd based systems now.

On Fedora with Plymouth, this behavior just happens automatically with the default setup.

> 

```
    * The "ask-password" framework used to query for LUKS harddisk
      passwords or SSL passwords during boot gained support for
      caching passwords in the kernel keyring, if it is
      available. This makes sure that the user only has to type in
      a passphrase once if there are multiple objects to unlock
      with the same one. Previously, such password caching was
      available only when Plymouth was used; this moves the
      caching logic into the systemd codebase itself. The
      "systemd-ask-password" utility gained a new --keyname=
      switch to control which kernel keyring key to use for
      caching a password in. This functionality is also useful for
      enabling display managers such as gdm to automatically
      unlock the user's GNOME keyring if its passphrase, the
      user's password and the harddisk password are the same, if
      gdm-autologin is used.
```

https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2015-October/034509.html